How does Grover's operator work - specifically applying the H gate in the operator
I am following this video and the professor applies an H gate at the start of the reflection operator (one H gate was applied at the beginning of the main circuit) - doesn't that mean that the qubits return back to their initial states (which I'm pretty sure default to zero)?
Thanks

Welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Unfortunately, that is not a great video to try to learn about Grover's algorithm. Try this one: https://youtu.be/GG71jyWOOPQ?si=21l-1uMka7dkaG-U
